# Rest Client adding json body return MESSAGE_NOT_READABLE

Tags: c#, rest-client

I am trying to use RestClient in C#

```
var client = new RestClient(signUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(signUrl, Method.Put);
```

How can I add the following JSON to the request Body

```
{
  "device_configuration_general": {
    "id": "fffc16e2-2cf3-40f6-92df-a5b65e617b1c"
  }
}
```

I've tried

```
var body = "{\"device_configuration_general\": {\"id\": \"f60c3043-cedc-4d2e-b713-5c5dce842dc4}}"

request.AddBody(body);

RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

but getting

```
"{\"code\":\"MESSAGE_NOT_READABLE\",\"message\":\"JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\",\"serviceName\":\"Device Service\",\"traceId\":\"adf3a952f0585e7d\",\"environment\":\"dev\",\"details\":null}"
```

I also tried

```
var body = "{\"device_configuration_general\": {\"id\": \"e8729ce5-e741-4b17-844e-e129133de49e\",}}"
```

but getting:

```
"{\"code\":\"MESSAGE_NOT_READABLE\",\"message\":\"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\",\"serviceName\":\"Device Service\",\"traceId\":\"55804813c2f97aae\",\"environment\":\"dev\",\"details\":null}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add JSON body to the request body:

```
request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { 
    ContentType = "application/json",
    Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, 
    Value = body
});
```